# Output text between two regular expression patterns over multiple lines

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I can run the following command if I bring `myfile` to an environment with `python` available:

```
cat myfile | python filter.py
```

filter.py

```
import sys

results = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    results.append(line.rstrip("\n\r")) 

start_match = "some text"
lines_to_include_before_start_match = 4
end_match = "some other text"
lines_to_include_after_end_match = 4

for line_number, line in enumerate(results):
    if start_match in line:
        for x in xrange(line_number-lines_to_include_before_start_match, line_number):
            print results[x]

        print line

        for x in xrange(line_number+1, len(results)):       
            if end_match in results[x]:
                print results[x]

                for z in xrange(x+1, x+lines_to_include_after_end_match):
                    print results[z]

                break
            else:
                print results[x]

        print ""
```

But the environment that I want to run this in doesn't have python.  Is my only choice to convert this to perl, which I know exists in the environment?  Is there an easy sed or awk command to do this?

I've tried the following but it doesn't quite give me what I'm looking for since it misses the +/- 4 lines:

```
cat myfile | sed -n '/some text/,/some other text/p'
```

[EDIT: The python script says lines_to_include_after_end_match is 4 but in reality it returns 3]

Answer (score 0):

Given that the line endings are `\n`, you can try this:

```
awk '/some text/{if(l4)printf l4;p=5} /some other text/{e=1} e && p {p--; if (!p) {e=0;l4="";}} !p && !e { l4 = l4 $0 "\n"; sub(/[^\n]*\n(([^\n]*\n){4})/,"\1",l4);} p' file
```

Note the mark needs be 6 if you want print extra 4 lines after the end match.
I think your own python code will only print another 3 lines after end match.

Put in several lines for redability:

```
awk '/some text/{if(l4)printf l4;p=5} 
    /some other text/{e=1} 
    e && p {p--; if (!p) {e=0;l4="";}} 
    !p && !e { l4 = l4 $0 "\n"; sub(/[^\n]*\n(([^\n]*\n){4})/,"\1",l4);} 
    p' file
```

Comment: Yes, you're right.  My python script should only print out 3 lines, which is what I wanted it to do.  I'll update the original post to note that.

Comment: I tried the `awk` command but it seems like it returns the next p-1 lines after finding "some text" and then the 3 lines before the first instance of  "some other text".  I was hoping to get the 4 lines before "some text", all the text between "some text" and the first instance of "some other text" after that instance of "some text", and the next 3 lines after "some other text"

Comment: Yes, there are multiple instances of `some text` and `some other text`.

Comment: awk version 20070501

Comment: @Joel Updated. Try it again please, see if it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n/&/4;Ta};/1st text/{:b;n;/2nd text/!bb;:c;N;s/\n/&/4;Tc;b};$d;D' file
```

Open up a window of n lines and if those lines contain `1st text` print them and continue printing until `2nd text`, then read m further lines and print those. Otherwise , if it is the end of the file delete the buffered lines else delete the first line in the buffer and repeat.

If the match text begin at start or end of a line, use:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;s/\n/&/4;Ta};/^start/M{:b;n;/end$/M!bb;:c;N;s/\n/&/4;Tc;b};$d;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`, please try:

```
sed -n "$(($(sed -n '/some text/=' myfile) - 4)),$(($(sed -n '/some other text/=' myfile) + 4))p" myfile
```

- The command `sed -n '/some text/='` returns the line number which matches `some text`.
- Then 4 is subtracted from the number above.
- The next part `sed -n '/some other text/='` works similarly and the obtained line number is added by 4.

Note that the script scans the input file three times and may not be suitable for the case execution time is crucial.

[Edit]

In case you have multiple `"some other text"` in the file, please try instead:

```
sed -n "$(($(sed -n '/some text/=' myfile) - 4)),\$p" myfile | sed "/some other text/{N;N;N;q}"
```

Comment: While I think this approach is pretty clever, the issue with this "some other text" appears many times in the file and I want to only grab the text between "some text" (including previous 4 lines) and the first instance of "some other text" (including next 3 lines).

Comment: Hmm.. I've had a concern about such a possibility :). I've updated my answer. Would you please try it?